# Changed PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 with Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, php-7, php-5.6

I changed the version of PHP [5.6.30] to PHP [7.0.17]. But now Magento 1.9.2.1 returns the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

I tried the following solutions:

1. https://gist.github.com/MageMechanic/66449504110fbbd96214
2. http://afilina.com/magento-1-9-on-php7/

But the error is still there.

Comment: You could try to install: https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7, or this might do the trick: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-mysql-old-password

Comment: I only need to update password of MySql and it worked.  Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340488/mysql-php-incompatibility/1340538#1340538

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart mysql0. Looks like your sql has stopped.

Comment: I posted the answer in comment above.

Comment: Ok great, sorry didn't see it @Jai